# Modifying the URL in Preview button in wagtail when editing a page

Tags: wagtail

I'm using a wagtail as a headless CMS. I want to enable users of this CMS to easily see the preview of the page on a SPA. I've overridden APIs to expose draft pages with help of token.

The only part I'm stuck at is modifying the URL in the `Preview` button to redirect to the SPA so that they can hit the API, get the data and render the page.

Is there any way I can override the URL of the `preview` button or just be able to add another action to see preview of the page on a SPA?

Comment: https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-headless-preview may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Wagtail Headless](https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-headless-preview)

`pip install wagtail-headless-preview`

`HEADLESS_PREVIEW_CLIENT_URLS = {
     'default': 'http://localhost:8020/',
 }`

Add HeadlessPreviewMixin to your page class:

`from wagtail_headless_preview.models import HeadlessPreviewMixin`

`class MyWonderfulPage(HeadlessPreviewMixin, Page):
    pass`

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ajax for something like this:

```
 function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
 document.title = response.pageTitle;
 window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);~}
```

Answer (score 0):

`wagtail-headless-preview` is designed to solve this exact problem:

https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-headless-preview